# Comparing two different column values for the records having same primary key value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare the two columns (date1 and date2) for same ID and set the value of column NewColumn to 'Yes' if date1 matches with the previous date2.

INPUT:

| ID | Date1 | date2 | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 Jan 2022 | 1 Feb 2022 |  |
| 1 | 1 Feb 2022 | 2 Feb 2022 |  |
| 1 | 7 Feb 2022 | 8 Feb 2022 |  |
| 2 | 2 Feb 2022 | 2 Feb 2022 |  |
| 3 | 2 Feb 2022 | 3 Feb 2022 |  |

Input in CSV format:

```
ID,date1,date2,NewColumn
1,31/01/2022,01/02/2022, 
1,01/02/2022,02/02/2022, 
1,07/02/2022,08/02/2022,
2,02/02/2022,02/02/2022,
3,02/02/2022,03/02/2022,
```

Output:

| ID | date1 | date2 | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 Jan 2022 | 1 Feb 2022 |  |
| 1 | 1 Feb 2022 | 2 Feb 2022 | YES |
| 1 | 7 Feb 2022 | 8 Feb 2022 |  |
| 2 | 2 Feb 2022 | 2 Feb 2022 |  |
| 3 | 2 Feb 2022 | 3 Feb 2022 |  |

In CSV format:

```
ID,date1,date2,NewColumn
1,31/01/2022,01/02/2022, 
1,01/02/2022,02/02/2022, YES
1,07/02/2022,08/02/2022,
2,02/02/2022,02/02/2022,
3,02/02/2022,03/02/2022,
```

Comment: could you please edit your post and show the data as comma-separated data?

Comment: sure , i have edited the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to apply a custom function to each group. The function then needs to compare the `date1` with the previous row's `date2` which can be done using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). This will give a boolean value (True or False), to get a string value you can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). For example:

```
import numpy as np

def func(x):
    return x['date1'] == x['date2'].shift(1)

df['NewColumn'] = np.where(df.groupby('ID').apply(func), 'YES', '')
```

Result:

```
   ID  date1           date2         NewColumn
0   1  31/01/2022      01/02/2022   
1   1  01/02/2022      02/02/2022       YES
2   1  07/02/2022      08/02/2022   
3   2  02/02/2022      02/02/2022   
4   3  02/02/2022      03/02/2022
```